# Why don't default operators support templated implementations?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a bunch of subclasses that all implement a default version of `operator==`. Instead of each derived subclass defining its own `operator==` for that particular subclass, I thought I'd template the base class and create a default `operator==` implementation there that uses the template parameter.

However, the following won't compile under either latest clang or gcc (at least those on godbolt) with `-std=c++23`:

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
class Base
{
    bool operator==(const Derived&) const = default;
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{

};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

GCC says:

> `<source>:4:10: error: defaulted member 'bool Base<Derived>::operator==(const Derived&) const' must have parameter type 'const Base<Derived>&'`

Clang says

> `<source>:4:10: error: invalid parameter type for defaulted equality comparison operator; found 'const Derived &', expected 'const Base<Derived> &'`

But I'm not really sure what this error here means, how can I pass `Base<Derived>` to `operator==`? Am I specialising `Derived` incorrectly? Or is this something not supported by the standard?

If I provide a concrete implementation to `operator==` it compiles fine.

Comment: The operator you wrote would be equivalent to `operator==(const Base<Derived>&, const Derived&)`. It isn't clear to me either how a default implementation of that should look like.

Comment: there is an unfortunate clash of name `Derived` you have one template argument called like that and one type called like that. In priciple the two are unrelated. I suggest to forget about the class definition of `Derived` for a moment, perhaps then it is easier to see whats wrong in `Base` and why it isnt obvious what the `=default` implementation of that operator should be.

Comment: The problem is that defaulted comparison `operator==` must have the parameter type as `const class-name&`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai would perhaps a `friend` function illustrate my intent better? I just want to avoid writing a bunch of `bool operator==(const DerivedClass&) const = default;` in every `DerivedClass` that I have. However, a `friend` version of this suffers from the same problem.

Comment: not sure if I can follow. THis is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want us to help with your actual problem you can open a new question to ask about that. The quesiton here is only about what you thought was a solution, it got its answer, its just not the right way to solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

**tldr;**

The comparison `operator==` with parameter `const Derived&` isn't allowed by the c++ grammar rules.

---

We're only allowed to default a comparison `operator==` if its parameter have the parameter type as `const class-name&`.

This can be seen from [default comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons):

> ```
> return-type class-name ::operatorop
>    (const class-name &) const &(optional) = default;
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Note that the parameter is `const class-name&` while you're providing `const Derived&`. This means that the parameter should be `const Base&` in order for this to work.

Comment: But then I'd be using the `Base` class version, no? My intent is to just avoid repeating myself and having a bunch of `bool operator==(const DerivedClass&) const = default;` in every `DerivedClass` that subclasses `Bases`.

Comment: @Nobilis You can use a *using declaration* for `opeator==` in the derived classes.

Comment: @Nobilis See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jnKsMdnss) that uses the *using declaration* in the derived class.

Comment: I thought about it but does that not suffer from the same problem where I'm using the base class version rather than generating a version for the derived class?